# How to handle operator == overload when the right hand side is of type Object

Tags: c#, overloading, operator-keyword

In the below example I have created a class named 'Custom' that implements IComparable:

```
public int CompareTo(Object value)
{
    // comparison logic here
}
```

Implementations of CompareTo(Object) are generally "forgiving" in that they will cast 'value' to a more specific type.  In this case, a cast to the type 'Custom' will be performed so a comparison can be made.  Imagine I also overload the == operator:

```
public static bool operator== (Custom lhs, Custom rhs)
{
    // equivalence test here
}
```

The problem I've run into is in this case:

```
Custom c = GetCustomObject();
Object o = GetOtherObject();
if(c == o)
{
     // will not be true unless c and o are the same object
}
```

The problem is that when == is invoked, because the rhs is of type 'Object', it falls back to the default test for reference equality - the overload is not called.

What is the expectation here?  I can add another overload for the == operator:

```
public static bool operator== (Custom lhs, Object rhs)
```

But examples like this are noticeably absent from MSDN or other online examples.  This makes me think that the test for reference equality is the expected behavior

Comment: Why would you like to assign you instance to `object` variable on the first place?

Comment: Not every library in .NET takes full advantage of generics, sometimes by necessity. There are plenty of cases where some framework code gives you `System.Object`s and you are expected to cast (e.g. WPF converters, dependency properties)

Comment: Silly question maybe, did you override Equals as well?

Comment: Remember that `==` is *not virtual/polymorphic*. (And unlike C++ or a language with multiple-dispatch, operators cannot be added to existing types to handle the case when the l/r operands are swapped.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This makes me think that the test for reference equality is the expected behavior

This is correct.

It is very rarely useful to implement this in any other way, due to the fact that `==` is dispatched on the static type of the variables. If you implement `==(YourClass, Object)` then this:

```
YourClass x = new YourClass();
if (x == someObject) { ... }
```

Will behave differently to:

```
Object x = new YourClass();
if (x == someObject) { ... }
```

This is usually unexpected!

So, if you want virtually-dispatched equality you should just use `Equals`.

There is only one type in `System` that implements an `==` with different argument types, and it's very special ([RuntimeTypeHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fzcch91%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

`(c == o) = false` is totally expected. Remember, you are overloading! the operator. Your operator overload `public static bool operator== (Custom lhs, Custom rhs)` is not working because you don't have `public static bool operator== (Custom lhs, Object rhs)`. Now that you have it, it makes a little sense, right?

So the solution is to use interface or base class. Comparing 2 unrelated objects doesn't make sense anyway. As you found out, .Net does it for you well already. But comparing related objects in a custom way makes perfect sense:

```
public static bool operator== (ICustom x, ICustom y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for some special group of sealed types (or reference types that pretend to be value type like string) it may be ok idea to provide `==` with an `object` as a way to short-circuit equality inside the group.

I would not expect such comparison to work for non-sealed types (and compile time error is easy way to let people know something is not right here) as there is way to many options such code would behave wrong with derived classes. Reference comparison should be enough.

For `==` to work reasonably you need 6 overrides for each combination of types: `(Custom,object)`, `(Custom,Custom)`, `(object,Custom,` and  both operators: `==`/`!=` .

```
 public static bool operator != (object lhs, Custom rhs)
 {
return !(lhs==rhs);
 }
 public static bool operator == (object lhs, Custom rhs)
 {
   // equivalence test here
return true;
 }
```

To have it working correctly you need all sorts of `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to match above behavior.